# What happens when you put water under intense pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, water, phase-transition, phase-diagram

Pretend you have an indestructible tube that cannot leak, inside which is water. Imagine that in each side of the tube, you have very powerful pistons

What would happen if you compress the water inside?

Would it turn into heat and escape the tube?

Would the water turn into solid because the water molecules are so close to each other?

Would the water turn into a black hole?
What would happen?

Comment: the disappointing but truthful answer: no black hole and water is very very incompressible - water at 40MPa only has a 1.8% decrease in volume, so not a lot would happen

Comment: see [what happens to water under high pressures without possibility of escape?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9803/) and [hypothetical : what happens to water as pressure increases to infinity?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/20009/) on Chemistry SE.

Comment: It's funny how the answer on chemistry site is more detailed than the answer here. I hope someone will add a higher-quality answer to this question.

Comment: The highest-rated answer on the chemistry site implicitly assumes that compression increases temperature, which is not necessarily true. The pressure and temperature of a system can be controlled independently.

Comment: See also the related question at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9665/what-happens-if-you-try-to-freeze-water-in-an-water-tight-container/16734

Comment: I recall reading 2-3 days ago of the discovery of a previously unobserved (but hypothesized) form of "ice", embedded in natural diamonds, and presumed to have formed under intense pressure.  (Sorry, I have no way to find a reference.)

Comment: @sammygerbil That makes sense, as physics is just generalized chemistry.

Answer (score 87):

What you're asking about is usually shown in a phase diagram. The diagram shows how the "phase", i.e. liquid, gas, or one of various solid phases, exists at different temperatures and pressures:

[image: phase diagram for water]

If your cylinder starts at say $20{}^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ and atmospheric pressure, it'll be in $\color{green}{\textbf{Liquid}}$ right near the center of the diagram.  If you raise the pressure keeping the temperature constant, it'll switch to $\color{blue}{\textbf{Ice VI}}$ at about 1GPa, or about 10,000 atmospheres of pressure: it's *hard* to turn water to ice by compressing it; the water at the bottom of the ocean is still water.

As you keep raising the pressure further, keeping the temperature constant, it'll go through more and more compact forms of solid ice (the diagram doesn't show "black hole", as that would be many, many orders of magnitude off the top, and can't be physically reached).

I stress "keeping the temperature constant" because (a) that's something your experiment will have to choose to do or not do and (b) because it makes it much easier to read the diagram.  The compression is adding energy to the water, from the work done by the pistons.  If you go slow, and the cylinder isn't insulated, etc, that energy will conduct away as the cylinder naturally stays the temperature of its environment. If you go fast, or the cylinder is insulated, the temperature will rise and the water will tend to go up-and-right in the diagram: You'll hit the transitions at different points.

Comment: If I'm reading that diagram correctly, it actually appears to be easier to turn ice into water at -20C using pressure than to turn water into ice at 20C using pressure. That's pretty interesting.

Comment: Could you link a source for the phase diagram? It might have some related background information on experimental setups.

Comment: The diagram is from WikiCommons: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_diagram_of_water.svg

Comment: @KamilDrakari I may be misunderstanding your observation, but surely it isn't surprising that it is easy to turn water into ice at -20C, since that's 20 degrees below the standard freezing point of water...

Comment: @Dancrumb the turning is in the other direction (ice → water).

Comment: Where's ice IV? And XII - XIV?

Comment: The conspicuous absence of the "black hole" region made my day.

Comment: @KamilDrakari This is known as [regelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regelation)

Comment: @J... Note that before black hole you'd hit "fusion" and ["white dwarf"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_degeneracy_pressure) and ["neutron star"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter#Neutron_degeneracy) phases.  There is a possibilty [Quark star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter#Quark_degeneracy) matter could even stop things before a black hole forms.  I'd note, however, that the "infinite strength" of the other materials involved will probably cause singularities in the physics long before you hit a black hole...

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, I think all phase diagrams need to show this.  I mean, this *is* science, after all.  If you're not committed to the full story then, well... what's the point?!

Comment: A closely-related question was asked some time ago on Chem.SE ("Is it always possible to solidify water by compressing it, regardless of the temperature?"). [This answer to that question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/30778/4921) includes a theoretical phase diagram for water at interior-of-Neptune pressures and temperatures.  There's a _lot_ of intermediate stages to get through between Ice XI and black hole.

Comment: @BobJacobsen To add, [here is a link](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/ice_phases.html) explaining further ice phases, up until ice 17.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann thanks - reading comprehension failure on my part :/

Comment: @KamilDrakari: Yep!  It's actually related to why ice floats.  The crystal structure for ice Ih is less densely packed than water is, so increasing the pressure makes the denser water more stable than the less dense ice.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Creating those alternative forms requires more complex transitions than the phase diagram can show simply. Ice IV for instance forms only sometimes, it is "meta-stable" and its domain on the diagram overlaps with III, V and VI.

Answer (score 46):

#### Short version

- Around ${10}^{5}\mathrm{Pa}$, which is about normal atmospheric pressure, water's liquid.
- Around ${10}^{9}\mathrm{Pa}$, water's compressed into ice.  Ice configuration varies as pressure increases.
- Around ${10}^{12}\mathrm{Pa}$, the ice metallizes.  It's no longer a bunch of H<sub>2</sub>O molecules, but rather a soup of H and O atoms.
- Around ${10}^{16}\mathrm{Pa}$, very roughly, nuclear reactions might start to become appreciable (though not exactly common).
- Around ${10}^{31}\mathrm{Pa}$, pressures approach what's found in a neutron star.  It's no longer meaningful to speak of individual atoms.
- At some point, it probably collapses into a black hole, or something.
- Past that, it'd be rampant speculation.

---

#### Long version

Roughly, works kinda like this:

1. Start at a typical temperature/pressure; let's say $20{}^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ and $1{\cdot}{10}^{5}\mathrm{Pa}~\left(\approx1~\mathrm{atm}\right)$.
2. Compress, assuming that the cylinder is in a heat bath of constant temperature.

   - Another common option is to consider an adiabatic compression, in which heat is trapped too, such that temperature'll tend to increase as it's compressed.  Doing isothermal instead because it's lazier.
3. As pressure increases, a few minor effects will happen:

   - Water'll lose some volume (though it's not too compressible).
   - Heat'll get generated (though it'll be lost to the heat bath).
   - The chemical equilibrium will shift a bit.
4. Around $P{\approx}1{\cdot}{10}^{9}\mathrm{Pa}$, the liquid water will start to compress into ice.

   - Specifically, the water molecules will arrange themselves into an *Ice VI* pattern.
5. Around $P{\approx}2{\cdot}{10}^{9}\mathrm{Pa}$, the *Ice VI* pattern might start to lose way to *Ice VII*.
6. Around $P{\approx}6{\cdot}{10}^{9}\mathrm{Pa}$, the *Ice VII* pattern might start to lose way to *Ice X*.
7. Beyond this point, things start to get speculative as we're outside the realm of experimental verification.

   The plot in [@BobJacobsen's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/394960/142085) shows a prediction of a variation of *Ice XI*, as does this slightly extended plot:

   [image]
8. As pressures increase further, it stops being "*water*", but instead a metal composed of the atoms that used to be in the water.  The difference is that, pre-metallization, water is H<sub>2</sub>O; after metallization, it's no longer meaningful to speak of individual molecules of H<sub>2</sub>O, much like it's not meaningful to speak of "*molecules*" of typical metals.

   Exactly when and how metallization happens is controversial.  There're competing claims for when hydrogen metallizes, and I found a claim that oxygen metallizes relatively soon too, and then another claim that water would metallize at another pressure:

   - $P{\approx}2.5{\cdot}{10}^{10}\mathrm{Pa}$: [Early prediction](https://doi.org/10.1063%2F1.1749590) of hydrogen's metallization.
   - $P{\approx}9.6{\cdot}{10}^{10}\mathrm{Pa}$:  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_pressure) cites oxygen going metallic.
   - $P{\approx}4.95{\cdot}{10}^{11}\mathrm{Pa}$:  There's a contested experimental claim to having observed [metallic hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen).
   - $P{\approx}1.55{\cdot}{10}^{12}\mathrm{Pa}$:  Claim for water (so both hydrogen and oxygen together) going metallic:

     > Based on density functional calculations we predict water ice to attain two new crystal structures with Pbca and Cmcm symmetry at 7.6 and 15.5 Mbar, respectively. The known high pressure ice phases VII, VIII, X, and Pbcm as well as the Pbca phase are all insulating and composed of two interpenetrating hydrogen bonded networks, but the Cmcm structure is metallic and consists of corrugated sheets of H and O atoms. The H atoms are squeezed into octahedral positions between next-nearest O atoms while they occupy tetrahedral positions between nearest O atoms in the ice X, Pbcm, and Pbca phases.
     >
     > -["New Phases of Water Ice Predicted at Megabar Pressures"](http://militzer.berkeley.edu/papers/ice26.pdf) [formatting omitted]
9. At some [pretty ambiguous point](http://solar-center.stanford.edu/FAQ/Qfusion_TP.html), nuclear reactions'll probably start to become significant, likely with hydrogen's going to helium, etc..  Since nuclear reactions have started, we're outside the realm of chemistry.
10. Eventually, the matter'll probably become [degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter).  Naively, I kinda picture something like a [neutron star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star), where increasing the pressure would be like digging deeper into a neutron star's layers:

    [image]

    But, obviously, we're deep into the realm of speculation at this point.
11. Eventually the degeneracy pressure is overcome, and it'll form a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole), maybe.  Perhaps it'll look like a [fuzzball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_(string_theory)), maybe.  Don't really know.

---

#### Discussion on high-pressure ice

For the extreme range of pressures in which water is still "*water*", [this source](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/ice_phases.html#TPa) seems to have a good discussion:

> **Very high-pressure ices including superionic ice**
>
> The state of ice at the very high pressures above ice X has only recently been reached experimentally. Modeling gives a confusion of possibilities. As such modeling, but of lower pressure ices, does not give accurate results as compared with experimental structure information, it is expected that these results are, at best, indicative. Density functional calculations [1709] indicate a pressure-induced initial displacement of the ice-ten atomic layers to give an orthorhombic Pbcm structure. At higher pressure, this may be followed by the squeezing of the H-atoms from their midpoints to give a Pbca structure and then, at over a terapascal (TPa, 10<sup>7</sup> atm), to a metallic ice, consisting of corrugated sheets of H and O atoms with the H-atoms at the octahedral midpoints between next-nearest oxygen atoms [1709]. Alternative views have been given; one is that the orthorhombic Pbcm structure is superseded by a _Pmc_2<sub>1</sub> phase above 930 GPa, followed by a _P_2<sub>1</sub> crystal structure at about 1.3 TPa and finally the metallic C2∕m phase above about 4.8 TPa [1818]. Another study shows that trigonal P3121 and orthorhombic Pcca phases become stable in the ranges 0.77-1.44 TPa and 1.44-1.93 TPa [2114] respectively. Such ices are not molecular and may be considered as protons and oxygen dianions with mobile electrons [1666] and are expected at the core of giant planets such as Jupiter and Saturn A partially ionic phase consisting of alternate layers of OH<sup>-</sup> and H<sub>3</sub>O<sup>+</sup> at low temperatures has been suggested [1810]. Several new phases may convert into one where the coordination number of oxygen increases from 4 to 5 with a significant increase of density [1818]. At pressures over about 5 TPa, it has been suggested that a phase splitting occurs with (the components of) H<sub>2</sub>O decomposing into a cubic Pa-3 H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> -formula phase and a hydrogen-rich phase, with metallization predicted at a higher pressure of just over 6 TPa [2114].
>
> A new superionic phase was proposed with an approximate triple point of about 1000 K, 40 GPa with liquid (supercritical and ionized) water and ice-seven at high temperatures (~1500K) [1572]. In this phase, the hydrogen ions (protons) were expected to be highly mobile, behaving like a liquid, and moving within the solid lattice of oxygen ions.The recent experimental discovery of superionic ice has reinforced this prediction [3199]. Using shock compression of ice-seven, it was shown that ice melts near 5000 K at 190 GPa.
>
> -["Water Structure and Science"](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/ice_phases.html#TPa) [links omitted; formatting partially reproduced]

Comment: According to this article http://science.sciencemag.org/content/283/5398/44.full, water only enters a metal phase at >5000K.  At room temperature the paper says the "oxygens solidify in an amorphous state, whereas the protons are still highly diffusing".  And at temperatures between those of the amorphous solid and metallic states, are ionic liquid and superionic solid phases.

Comment: @DavePhD Good find!  Skimming it real quick, looks like they explore up to about $3{\cdot}{10}^{11}\mathrm{Pa}$, whereas the [cited study](http://militzer.berkeley.edu/papers/ice26.pdf) claiming water's metallization puts it at about $1.55{\cdot}{10}^{12}\mathrm{Pa}$.  It appears that the cited study was aware of the one you'd linked, as it's Reference (16) in their paper.

Comment: @DavePhD Or, at least, they cite it as "_C. Cavazzoni, G. L. Chiarotti, S. Scandolo, E. Tosatti, M. Bernasconi, and M. Parrinello. Nature, 283:44, 1999._"; same authors, same year, and the content description superficially appears consistent, but the citation attributes it to _Nature_ rather than _Science_?  That seems odd - 1999's a little before my time, but did they used to dual-list papers, or maybe the citation's an error?

Comment: At what temperature is the 1.55 x 10^12 Pa?

Comment: @DavePhD It's shown in the phase diagram above.  I added that one instead of Wikipedia's since it includes the metallic phase.

Comment: @DavePhD [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25165937) puts metallization at $6{\cdot}10^{12}\mathrm{Pa}$, which it claims $\text{H}_2\text{O}$ is thermodynamically unstable at, such that it'll convert to $\text{H}_2\text{O}_2$ before metallizing (at equilibrium).  Weird, though - I'd have thought that, when talking about significant metallization, the conversation would've already shifted from "_molecules_" to "_formula units_", such that talk of "_molecules_" decomposing into others sounds a bit strange.

Comment: Between 16 and 31 there is electron degeneracy.  The interesting thing about nuclear reactions is that they are a dynamic response to increased pressure; a steady pressure (or volume) results in more and more of the matter fuzing into iron (or later) and no longer being able to maintain a counter-pressure with nuclear reactions.

Comment: @Yakk I asked a question about the electron-degeneracy-vs.-metallization thing here: ["What's the transition from “metal” to “electron-degenerate matter” look like?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/396175/whats-the-transition-from-metal-to-electron-degenerate-matter-look-like).

Comment: @hyde I asked a question about the electron-degeneracy-vs.-metallization thing here: ["What's the transition from “metal” to “electron-degenerate matter” look like?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/396175/whats-the-transition-from-metal-to-electron-degenerate-matter-look-like).