# How much water is needed for its weight to cause fusion?

Tags: pressure, nuclear-physics, thought-experiment

Assuming we have a cylinder with an interior volume equal to one milliliter per centimeter of cylinder height and it is filled with water.  Also assume earth gravity and the cylinder is unbreakable.  How high would it (the cylinder) need to be before the pressure on the water at the bottom triggers fusion?

Comment: Maybe this article will help in understanding fusion https://science.howstuffworks.com/fusion-reactor2.htm

Comment: The following question and answers contains useful information.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/394943/90326